# how to print a triangle in java without inner stars

Tags: java

The following code gives me the results but I want to make it more simple so i can learn logic of different scenario

```
    public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5 - i; x++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
     }
   }
```

But now i want to make a triangle without inner stars and i am not getting a logic i am trying and thinking for hours i don't  want full coding i just want a logic explanation so i can make it by my self it feels good

Comment: Hint: where you print a sequence of stars, you just want the first and last, the rest needs to be replaced by empty space.

Comment: Break it down into basic elements. First will be * then space and then * and if you unable to figure it out try some basic questions of triangle patterns like [this](http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2016/01/c-program-to-print-hollow-rectangle.html) and still not then ask where you are stuck

Comment: @BrijRajKishore i figure it out  without using loop give space and star then print step by step

Comment: @Raza I didn't said it without loop. I said you should break down the whole into 3 and try to observe the patterns of the space. The all left is easy. Just a star at beginning and end of space

Comment: @BrijRajKishore ok i will try to do it like you said

Comment: I forgot one thing, I am talking about here this kind of pattern like hollow right triangle which has perpendicular edges aligned like with your screen bottom left. But if you have to make like a pyramid type then you have to break it into 4 parts

Answer (score 0):

You want to print the first and last star in each row, so you need to check if `k` is the first or last value in your loop. Here's pseudocode:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
    [if k is first or last possible value]
        [print star]
    [else]
        [print space]
}
```